# Will this function return uniformly distributed random values?

Tags: c, random, statistics, probability, mersenne-twister

I'd like to return uniform random values in a range. The magnitude of the range and the minimum value are precomputed.

I'm using the reference implementation of the double precision Mersenne Twister distributed by the team at Hiroshima University. I'm currently using the `dsfmt_genrand_close_open()` function which has the following description:

*"generates and returns a double precision pseudorandom number which distributes uniformly in the range [0, 1)"*

This is the function:

```
uint64_t gen_addr_in_range (uint64_t range, uint64_t low_addr) {
    return (dsfmt_genrand_close_open(&dsfmt) * (range + 1)) + low_addr;
}
```

Is the output of this function uniform within the given range?

Comment: As a non-mathematician, I _believe_ that if `dsfmt_genrand_close_open` is uniform between `[0,1)` then if you multply it by a constant multiplier ( range + 1) then you should get equally random distribution.  Unrelated point: if you are getting a random address in a range (seems valid), why are you using uint64_t to store the address?  Shouldn't it be a `void *`?

Comment: These are addresses are data in a memory simulation

Answer (score 0):

As a non-mathematician:

A continuous uniform distribution has the form (programatically):

```
if (a <= x <= b)
    f(x) = 1/(b-a)
else
    f(x) = 0
```

Multiplying this distribution by a constant A would yield:

```
if (A*a <= x <= A*b)
    f(x) = 1/(A*b-A*a)
else
    f(x) = 0
```

which is another uniform distribution.

Similarly, scaling by a constant c would yield:

```
if ((a+c) <= x <= (b+c))
    f(x) = 1/((b+c)-(a+c))
else
    f(x) = 0
```

Which again is a uniform distribution.

I think you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to consider (assuming that `range` is limited to 32 bits) is this

```
return( low_addr + arc4random_uniform( range ) );
```

which generates a uniformly distributed value from `low_addr` to `low_addr + range - 1`.

Comment: A double has 53 bits in the mantissa, so it's less than "normal kill" rather than "overkill"

Comment: @OregonTrail  Excellent point, sir.  I failed to consider his use of 64-bit numbers, which arc4random_uniform won't support, unless the `range` parameter is limited to 32-bits.  And indeed, you have answered his original question, since his proposed rand function **cannot** generate a uniform distribution over the full 64-bit range since it only has 53 bits to work with.